# SharePoint custom TaxonomyField

Tags: sharepoint, taxonomy

Has anyone ever tried to create his own Managed Metadata field? Basically I need to extend functionality of that field with filtering terms shown in picker, based on current user permission.
Any clues where to start with this?
Regards
George

Comment: Hmm..thats a tough one. Would it be an alternative to maintain separate termsets? If that is the case, you could probably code your own picker and just load different termsets, for different users..

Comment: That would be an option if user has permission only to one node of the tree. Unfortunately my termset tree is deep and my users can have access to more than one subtree. What I was thinking about is finding the way to somehow override method for getting terms from termset.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a start with creating managed metadata fields in content type by following the steps mentioned here:
[Managed Metadata Fields SharePoint](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/03/the-complete-guide-to-provisioning-sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-fields/)

Hope it will be somehow helpful to you.